# How to publish my second version of a project on another collection on TFS?

Tags: tfs

When I try to upload a different version of my project on TFS, new collection, this message always appears:

> Your project exists `(URL of my project)` on an old collection

What's the problem when i upload the project that is different in two collections in the same TFS account?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project has been under version control. You could try to disconnect from TFS source control first, and then add it to another team project.

Disconnect from TFS source control:

1. Open the project in VS.
2. Go to File -- Source Control -- Advanced -- Change Source Control, and unbind the solution and projects.

[image]

3. Add the project to new team project and check in to new collection.